# CyclicBarrier and Thread for optimize for element for tags in Java

Tags: java, strings

How can I use a `CyclicBarrier` with N-THREAD according to my core for optimize this code?

My code has an input like this:

> ```
> i 3
> a duna automobile deserto -1 
> a nissan auto automobile -1 
> s aut -1
>
> i 2
> a pesca sport frutta -1
> s sport -1
>
> END
> ```

- `i = 3` means that there are 3 lines.
- "a" means that I'm adding an element (first occurrence after "a") and the other words after the element are my "tags".
- "s" means that I have to find the tags that have as substring the word "aut" for the first block and "sport" for the second block.

At the end the output is like this:

> ```
> 2
>
> 1
> ```

- "2" means that I have two elements "duna" & "nissan" that have tags (auto, automobile, auto) that start with the word "aut".
- "1" means that I have the element "pesca" that has tag (sport) that starts with the sub-tag "sport".

With `END`, the program is finished.

```
package Prove;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

class FinalMap {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {


        HashMap<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
        java.io.InputStreamReader isr = new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in);
        java.io.BufferedReader stdin = new java.io.BufferedReader(isr, 16 * 1024);

        String line = stdin.readLine();
        final String ADD_COMMAND = "a";
        final String ITEM_COMMAND = "i";
        final String SEARCH_COMMAND = "s";
        final String END_MARKER = "<END>";


        while (!line.equals("<END>")) {

            String elemento = "" ;


            if (line.startsWith(ITEM_COMMAND)) 
            {
                map = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
            }



            else if (line.startsWith(ADD_COMMAND)) {

                String[] parts = line.split("\\s+");

                for (int i = 2; i < parts.length - 1; ++i) {
                    String element = parts[1];
                    String tag = parts[i];
                    for (int j = 1; j <= parts[i].length(); ++j) {
                        String tagPrefix = tag.substring(0, j);
                        Set<String> elements = map.get(tagPrefix);
                        if (elements == null) {
                            elements = new HashSet<String>();
                            map.put(tagPrefix, elements);
                        }
                        elements.add(element);
                    }
                }


            }


            else if (line.startsWith(SEARCH_COMMAND)) {
                String subtag = line.substring(2,line.length()-3);
                if (map.containsKey(subtag)) {
                    System.out.println(map.get(subtag).size());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("missing");
                }
            }
           line = stdin.readLine();
        }
        stdin.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review.

Comment: Please see our guidelines for [asking a follow-up question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1066/31562). Your question seems to be a follow-up to [this one](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62346/performance-for-tags-for-cars-in-java)

Comment: I saw.This is a follow-up question because I changed the code and I would to know how to optimize more it

Comment: You can always go back to the previous question and look again: The opening and closing braces are still not used consistently, there's a lot of spacing and I'm not sure why. You also have a variable called END_MARKER yet you don't use it in your while loop. Seems you haven't fully addressed all the issues that they gave feedback on.

Answer (score 2):

```
        String elemento = "" ;
```

This variable is unused.

Additionally I'd clean up the blank lines you have, it's dangerous to have an if statement end, and then a couple blank lines later, there's an else that continues the if.

```
            for (int i = 2; i < parts.length - 1; ++i) {
                String element = parts[1];
                String tag = parts[i];
                for (int j = 1; j <= parts[i].length(); ++j) {
                    String tagPrefix = tag.substring(0, j);
                    Set<String> elements = map.get(tagPrefix);
                    if (elements == null) {
                        elements = new HashSet<String>();
                        map.put(tagPrefix, elements);
                    }
                    elements.add(element);
                }
            }
```

There's a performance optimization here; `parts[i].length()` is not free. Use `final int tagLength = parts[i].length()`, then test against that in your for-loop condition.